# Initializing a bidemensional array and change its values later

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I initialize a bidimensional array first and change its values later?

I've tried using the following code:

```
class foo
{
      public:
             foo()
             {
                  bar = {
                     {2, 2}, 
                     {2, 2}
                  };
             }

      private:
             int bar[2][2];
};

foo Foo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax only works when initializing an array. Inside your constructor body, the array has already been initialized. The only way to do that now is to use a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; i++)
        bar[i][j] = 2;
```

If you have the values in a global array or something, you can just copy them:

```
std::copy(values, values+sizeof(foo)/sizeof(int), foo);
```

Comment: @SpaceC0wb0y: Thanks for your answer! Can I also initialize the array inside the constructor body as property of the foo class? So that it can be used within the entire class?

Comment: @Datoxalas: As I said, you can do this using a loop (I removed the memset stuff, it was wrong).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I see, but I would like to keep the values in this way `bar = { {2, 2}, {2, 2} };` instead of `bar[i][j] = 2;` for every value. Is that possible?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I found a little workaround. First I initialize the array and then I create an array in the constructor and use your for loop to copy each of its values to the other array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Datoxalas: You can use `std::copy` for this: `std::copy(values, values+4, foo);`. But you have to make sure that `values` has the same size as `foo`.

Comment: In C++0x, you *can* initialize arrays in the constructor, with uniform initialization. `MyClass() : arr{ {2,2} , {2,2} } {...}` should work.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Thanks. I might be doing something wrong, but it's not working. I'm using this code: `int bar2[2][2] = { {2, 2}, {2, 4} };` and  `std::copy(bar2, bar2+sizeof(bar)/sizeof(int), bar);`

Comment: @Xeo: It's not working.. `class foo{ public:  foo() : arr{ {2, 2}, {2, 4} } { .. }`.
             {

Comment: I've found an easier way. Just using `memcpy()`. I've followed this tutorial: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13291 . :-) Thanks anyway. I kept getting the error `266 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\stl_algobase.h   instantiated from _OutputIterator std::__copy_aux2(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _OutputIterator, __false_type) [with _InputIterator = int (*)[2], _OutputIterator = int (*)[2]]'`